# JQuery get accurate element height with each()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-masonry, each

For some reason, I'm having trouble getting an accurate height value for elements in an `each()` loop when the page loads, but when I try the exact same `height()` function on `mouseleave`, it works fine. [See what I mean](http://www.whatworksforamerica.org/dev/ideas-that-work/)? It's supposed to be getting the height of the description `div`, and using that to determine the initial position.

I thought this might have to do with the images needing to load before the height was set, so the `load()` was an attempt to delay until after that. It does seem to make the height larger than without it, but still smaller than the actual height. Any ideas?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

var total = jQuery('.portfolio-item-holder figure').length;
var numLoaded = 0;

jQuery('.portfolio-item-holder img').one('load', function() {
  numLoaded++;
  if (numLoaded == total) {

    jQuery('.portfolio-item-holder figure').each(function(e) {
      var desc = jQuery(this).find('.description').outerHeight(true);
      console.log(desc);
      jQuery(this).find('figcaption').animate( { 'bottom' : -1 * desc }, 400, 'easeInOutQuart' );
    });

  }
}).each(function(){
  if(this.complete) jQuery(this).trigger('load');
});

jQuery('.portfolio-item-holder figure').bind('mouseenter', function(e) {

  var title = jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('h3').position();
  jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('figcaption').animate( { 'bottom' : '0', 'queue' : false }, 400, 'easeInOutQuart' ); 

}).mouseleave(function(e) {
  var desc = jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('.description').outerHeight(true);

  jQuery(e.currentTarget).find('figcaption').animate( { 'bottom' : -1 * desc, 'queue' : false }, 400, 'easeInOutQuart' ); 

});

});
```

Comment: Try changing from DOM ready to page load ( `$(window).load(fn)` ).

Comment: No change unfortunately…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes, when it doesn't work one way, try to make it work some other way. This is what I recommend:

**1)** In your CSS, 1a) set the `.description` class to `display:none;` and 1b) set the `.portfolio-item-holder figcaption` class to `bottom:0px;`

**2)** Set-up the mouse event handlers:

```
function PortfolioImageHandler() {

    $('#portfolio-item-holder').on({

          mouseenter: function () { ShowPortfolioDescription($(this)); },
          mouseleave: function () { HidePortfolioDescription($(this)); }

    }, '.portfolio-item');
}
```

**3)** Implement the event handlers:

```
function ShowPortfolioDescription(ThePortfolioItem) {
    ThePortfolioItem.find('.description').stop().slideDown(500);
}

function HidePortfolioDescription(ThePortfolioItem) {
    ThePortfolioItem.find('.description').stop().slideUp(200);
}
```

**4)** Change your code structure to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  //you should only have calls to other functions, no actual implementations
  //should be coded in the document.ready function; keep the handlers out of here
  PortfolioImageHandler();
});

function PortfolioImageHandler() {...}
function ShowPortfolioDescription (ThePortfolioItem) {...}
function HidePortfolioDescription (ThePortfolioItem) {...}
```

This will considerably reduce your code down to a few lines of code. Note that the `.stop()` function helps prevent the yoyo effect when the user repeatedly fires the mouseenter/mouseleave events: each event first cancels any ongoing animation before doing a `slideUp` or `slideDown`. Let me know how this works; here are 2 pics showing the result by manually modifying the settings in Chrome's inspector. BTW, if you look at the site in IE8, the way you had it setup wasn't going to work; the recommended implementation should work fine.

[image]

[image]

Follow-up: I'm seeing Ellen all the way. Is the output on your browser any different?

[image]

Comment: Wow, this works beautifully, and it's much simpler. Thank you! One question: if you look at the first `figure` in the largest viewport (> 1400px), you'll see there's a sort of jerky motion at the end. Did you notice this in your tests? It seems to be when `a.more` (part of `.description`) sits on its own line. In some cases it never slides all the way up (Ellen Seidman, third to last `figure`). Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not noticing any jerking and I added the last figure; seems fine too. May be you could add a little margin to add a few pixels of white space underneath.

Comment: I added some extra padding for cases when the "read more" isn't visible. It's strangely sporadic, and seems to happen more often when I use special easing (via the Easing plugin). Still production ready I think. Again, I thank you for your help!

Comment: I need a few more reputation points to vote it up, but will as soon as I can. :)

Comment: "Vote up requires 15 reputation." I just joined the site yesterday. I have 11. Not sure what I need to do to get 15.

Comment: ah ok, didn't remember that limit. Well keep coding away and you reputation will go up when you ask good questions that get upvoted, or when you provide answers.